# Plotly Timeline / Gantt Interactive Time Marker?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Would anyone know how to implement a functionality similar to the video playback selection timeline found in most video editor applications / youtube / timeline tools with plotly?

The idea would be that a user could click a specific point on the timeline that may or may not already have a data point and the application would page to that point and load data. For instance a corresponding image pic(t).

I would be interested in a pure python plotly method and or a dash method.

I have currently based my tool off of the example(s) here:

- https://plotly.com/python/gantt/
- https://dash.gallery/dash-alignment-chart/